# Points lose top css style while scrolling

Tags: css, scroll

I have an image on the screen with some bubbles that are randomly collocated and have top and left CSS styles to position them. However, when I scroll, all bubbles lose the top style and go to the bottom of the image.

Does anyone know a reason why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: There is  no way we can work out what is going wrong without seeing relevant code. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Remarkedly points lost their top CSS property but if you exchanged top with bottom, they won't lose their bottom property. So we did.